# Multiple Projects, android library

Tags: android-library

I need to create multiple projects from one source code.

1. Must have different logo, color backgrounds and fonts
2. Must have some constants defined differently
3. Each of these projects will be in different packages, else I wont be able to release them on the store.

I have developed a project that works, now I need to make this into a library project.

What I tried was

1. working project -> properties -> android -> is library
2. created a new project -> properties -> add -> working project
3. copied the android manifest from working to new project
4. exported the new project
5. installed it on the device, it shows in settings -> applications -> manage applications, but does not show as a app.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing out on 2 things

1. Changing the package name in the new project
2. Deleting the default ic_lanchner.png from all folders